# Why won't the border radius change?

Tags: flutter, dart

What am I doing wrong? I can't get the border radius of my card to change. The elevation isn't working either. I'm new at this. What do I need to change? Is it because it's in ListView? I'm confused. If you need for information, just ask. Sorry it wants me to write more... too much code?

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(85),
              child: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Color(),
                bottom: TabBar(
                  tabs: <Widget>[
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.people), text: (''),),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.person), text: (''),),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.circle), text: (''),),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

            body: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Card(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  elevation: 8.0,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    height: 120,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                          leading: CircleAvatar(backgroundImage:
NetworkImage(''),backgroundColor: Color(),),
                          title: Text('', style: TextStyle(color: Color ()),
                          subtitle: Text(
                            '', style: TextStyle(color: Color()),),),
                        Divider(
                          height: 10),

                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(Icons.add, color: Color()),
                                SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                                Text('', style: TextStyle(color: Color()),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(Icons.comment, color: Color()),
                                SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                                Text('', style: TextStyle(color: Color())),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(Icons.bookmark, color: Color()),
                                SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                                Text('', style: TextStyle(color: Color()),),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 12.0,),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is caused by the child container in the card widget. The container is overlapping over the cards borders so it covers the border radius and the elevation. Try putting the container as the parent of the card and see it that helps. Additionally,you could set the containers decorations property to have the same border radius as the card so it does not overlap.